# Get a folder / zip with files in changelist(s) in TFS with complete directory structure

Tags: deployment, tfs

Our team uses TFS to manage workflow in the following flow:
work item -> source control -> changelist -> manual deploy to servers

Is there any way to just get a list of files with complete directory structure for a given changelist? Ideally, I'd like to be able to select multiple changelists and/or work items to get all the changelists associated with a work item, and get a complete directory structure for files in the changelists/work items.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the following code snippit to get started

```
Uri tfsUri = new Uri(@"http://server:8080/tfs");
string serverPath = @"$/Project";

//Connect to the project collection
var projectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(
        tfsUri, new UICredentialsProvider());

//Get the source code control service. 
var sourceControl = projectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
var history = sourceControl.QueryHistory(
    serverPath,  //Source control path to the item. Like $/Project/Path ...
    LatestVersionSpec.Instance, //Search latest version
    0, //No unique deletion id. 
    RecursionType.Full, //Full recursion on the path
    null, //All users 
    new  ChangesetVersionSpec("9829"), //From the 7 days ago ... 
    LatestVersionSpec.Instance, //To the current version ... 
    Int32.MaxValue, //Include all changes. Can limit the number you get back.
    true, //Include details of items, not just metadata. 
    false //Slot mode is false. 
    );

//Enumerate of the changesets. 
foreach (Changeset changeset in history.OfType<Changeset>().Take(1))
{
    foreach (var change in changeset.Changes)
    {
        change.Item.ServerItem.Dump();
    }
}
```